# tilde key not working in Fedora Linux on Macbook Air

Tags: linux, keyboard, fedora, tilde

I am pretty much brand new to Linux and command line. I am trying to learn the commands and I got to a section that needed the ~ key. When I am using Fedora, the ~` key types ><. I have tried searching for this and I cannot find the answer. I have attempted many different fixes that I have found across multiple sites and the issue isn't resolved. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am using an American English Macbook Air, 13-inch mid 2013, model 6,2

Comment: Some google search gives: http://atodorov.org/blog/2015/04/30/fixing-tilde-and-function-keys-mapping-for-macbook-air-on-linux/

Comment: I tried that and it kept telling me that I didn't have permission.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer from this post:
https://superuser.com/a/622365

```
# clear all options
setxkbmap -model "pc105" -layout "hr,us" -option ""  

# set the Apple keyboard
setxkbmap -rules "evdev" -model "pc105" -layout "hr,us" -option "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,lv3:rwin_switch,grp:shifts_toggle,caps:ctrl_modifier,altwin:swap_lalt_lwin"

# swap the grave-tilde with less-greater key
#  - variant without dead keys
xmodmap -e "keycode  94 = grave asciitilde"
xmodmap -e "keycode  49 = less greater less greater bar brokenbar bar brokenbar"
```

Comment: xmodmap -pke
returns your current key mapping. (the '<' character is called 'less')
Then you can make a temporary change with
xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = asciitilde"

If that works save the whole map in ~/.Xmodmap
xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap